# Complete binary tree time complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, time-complexity, binary-tree

If someone wants to generates a complete binary tree. This tree has h levels where h can be any positive integer and as an input to the algorithm. What complexity will it lie in and why?

Comment: Presumably "generating a binary tree" takes time exactly proportional to the number of elements in a tree. With that assumption, all you have to do is calculate the number of elements in a complete binary tree of height *h*.

Comment: Any reasonable algorithm will spend constant time per node. So all you need is how many nodes are in a complete tree of height h.  Any aspiring programmer should want to figure that out for themselves rather than asking to be told the answer.  Sketch some complete trees of different heights, and the answer should become clear pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complete binary tree is tree where all levels are full of nodes except the last level, we can define the time complexity in terms of upper bound.

If we know the height of the tree is `h`, then the maximum number of possible nodes in the tree are 2<sup>h</sup> - 1.

Therefore, time complexity = O(2<sup>h</sup> - 1).

To sell your algorithm in the market, you need tight upper bounds to prove that your algorithm is better than the others'.

A slightly tight upper bound for this problem can be defined after knowing exactly how many nodes are there in the tree. Let's say there are `N`.

Then, the time complexity = O(N).

Comment: Thanks @Deepak for your valuable answer and time.

Comment: For voting I need 15 reputations, I did and corrected it too.